# Этимология русское ЗЕЛО

Tags: этимология

Сложный вопрос:
Этимологический словарь **Макса Фасмера** указывает, что
русское церковно-славянское **ЗЕЛО** родственно латинскому **GAILAS**?  (Фасмер, II, c.92)

На каком основании он это делает?
Ведь между ними нет ничего общего.

Неужели не найти было другого "родственника", более похожего на **ЗЕЛО** ?

Comment: А на поверку нет такого слова в латыни, зато есть в латышском. Но там другие значения-петух, например. Есть и в литовском.Либо Фасмер просто ошибся в сокращении  лат -лтш, либо сделал подстановку из других соображений.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Интересный ответ, спасибо! Но почему же такая цепочка - зело-зельный-гайлас-зейлас-зайлас-заилас - а не иная?
>
> Скажем, есть ведь в латинском свое ZELO, которое так и переводится - "горячо любить".
>
> Может, от него напрямую и получилось русское ЗЕЛО?

А это уже фантазии на тему случайного созвучия. 
То, что вы назвали "цепочкой", на самом деле есть некая общность по значению и фонетике в разных языках. *(Упомяну в скобках, что в отношении фонетики надо смотреть не просто созвучие, а и правила перехода звуков при заимствовании, о чем регулярно забывают любители "народной" этимологии).* Такая "цепочка" носит не просто иллюстрация, она само по себе есть аргумент или даже самое доказательство. Пусть и оспоримое, но веское.

А вот ZELO как источник невозсможно хотя бы потому, что латинское E не может соответствовать славянскому ятю. Ять - это именно "IE".

Comment: И это даже не смотря на то, что русс. ЗЕЛО ("очень") и лат. ZELO ("горячо любить") - слова одной семантики и одного корня?

По-Вашему тогда и русско-итальянская пара СТРАННЫЙ - STRANO не должна иметь между собой ничего общего!

Comment:  Правила перехода звуков только одно, неправильное произношение. Потом запись по этому неправильному произношению. Причем в различных системах записи. Таких переходов тьма тьмущая.
Процесс этот естественный. Оспаривать невозможно. А если учесть, что слово гуляет из языка в язык, от местности к местности, то порой и первоначальный смысл теряется, появляются новые значения. 

Случайности бывают, доказуемые. Частота этих случайностей слишком мала, они единичны.
Как правило совершенно не совпадают по смыслу и не имеют цепочек преобразований.

Comment: "Правила перехода звуков только одно - неправильное произношение".

СПАСИБО!
Думаю, этим ответом можно объяснить очень многие примеры, с одной стороны, "случайного созвучия" явных родственников (ЗЕЛО-ZELO, СТРАННЫЙ-STRANO), с другой - несоответствие "правил перехода звуков при заимствовании, о которых забывают любители народной этимологии".

В таком случае, ничего удивительного, что народная этимология процветает.То, что лингвистика называет несоответствием, является всего лишь неправильным произношением при заимствовании и, как следствие, соответствующей неправильной фиксацией норм письма.

Answer (score 3):

Как Вы заметили, ЗЕЛО - наречие церк.-слав. языка, когда-то оно писалось через ять (ст.-слав. ѕѣлъ σφοδρός, ѕѣло σφόδρα), а ять, как известно, изменился в е, и, я, созвучное а; чередование Г, Ж, З тоже известно, так что фонетическая общность есть: зело - зельный - гайлас - зейлас -зайлас - заилас. Было и прилагательное  зельный - сильный, обильный, великий, крепкий, в сильной степени, в больших размерах.

http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Dal-term-10572.htm

Comment: Интересный ответ, спасибо!
Но почему же такая цепочка - зело - зельный - гайлас - зейлас - зайлас -заилас - а не иная?

Скажем, есть ведь в латинском свое ZELO, которое так и переводится - "горячо любить".

Может, от него напрямую и получилось русское ЗЕЛО?

Comment: ZELO в латинском не "горячо любить",а "усердие".
В истории геральдики известен латинский девиз графов Аракчеевых «Labore et Zelo» — «Трудом и усердием») ,но в русском языке усердие-"большое старание" образовано от праславянского корня sьrdьce со значением "сердце". И латынь здесь ни при чем, как и в ЗЕЛО, а вот родственным латинскому GAILAS является по корню зел-зайл-гайл-гаил

Comment: Увы, словарь этого не подтверждает.
Вот результаты перевода:    
ZELO с итальянского - "усердие, рвение, старание".  
С латинского же - "горячо любить, возревновать" - как я и говорил ранее.

Вопрос остается прежним: почему этимологи не заметили лат. ZELO?

Заметьте! На самом деле здесь не имеет значения как именно переводится ZELO с латыни. Речь о том, что слово это в латинском языке есть, но вот упоминания о нем у Фасмера нет.
Почему?

Comment: zelo, avi, atum, are, чаще zelor, atus sum, ari (греч.) 
1) горячо любить (populum summo pietatis amore Tert); 
2) возревновать (zelo zelatus sum pro domino deo exerci - 
tuum Vlg). 
у Аракчеева--ревнительное отношение к службе государевой. Труд и рвение.
усердие- всего лишь синоним

Answer (score 0):

Ошибки у Макса Фасмера нет. Все дело в правилах славянской азбуки - кириллицы:

Как известно, в кириллице у буквы, помимо знака (символа), есть имя и цифровое обозначение:

Г- символ,
Глаголь – имя,
3 – цифровое значение,

Все три составляющие относятся к одной и той же букве, а значит, могут заменять друг друга.

Пример:

Гайлас – 3(три) айлас

Еще один способ замены возможен, исходя из графической идентичности знаков: цифра «3» графически то же самое, что и буква «З»

Гайлас – 3(три)айлас – Зайлас

Если «ас» или «аз» в конце слова – это имя буквы (знака) «А», то замена одного другим даст следующее:

Зайлас – зайлАз – зайлА  - зейло - зело

Второй вариант:

Если не брать в расчет произношение, то в слове GAILAS букву «I»  можно считать соединительной:

GAILAS – GA I LAS – GALAS – GALA (АS=Аз=А)
GALA – Гала - Зала – Зело

Третий вариант:

Зело – Гело – Гала – ГалАз – гайлас

Кириллические правила http://www.proza.ru/2006/06/05-293 позволяют увидеть насколько близки языки мира.